# 2023 Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

We are discussing scheduling a moderator election sometime in early 2023.  I would like to gather information on the level of interest in standing for election.

If you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, I would find it helpful if you would be willing to post an answer below. We're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start sometime in early 2023 -- January 2023 has been discussed.   I'm posting this now to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves when the actual election's nomination period starts, to avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates; and also to give you all some advance notice and hopefully get you thinking about running.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a sense of how many people here would be willing to step up.  No need to include an election nomination statement or any other materials, just information about your willingness to run.

If I can provide any information to help, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Answer (score 4):

If we're short of moderators, I'd like to throw my hat into the ring.