# Seeking volunteers to run for moderator

Tags: discussion, election

I need help.  Would you volunteer to run for moderator in the next election?

I think it's important for the site's health that we recruit another moderator to the moderation team.  There is a wide variance in how active the current moderators are.  We had an extended period of time where one of us was handling basically all flags, and that's not healthy.  If something happens to one of us, we could be suddenly left with only one moderator who can be active... or worse, with none.  Also, I don't think it's healthy in the long run for so many decisions to be made by one person; I think it's better to have more checks and balances among the moderator team.

If you're willing to self-nominate, would you leave an answer saying "I'll run!"?  I'm told that Stack Exchange will schedule an election if two or more of you are willing to run for election.

---

**Past election.**  We [tried](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1819/755) to hold an election earlier, but [only one person stood for election](https://cs.stackexchange.com/election/3#questionnaire), so [the election was cancelled](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2847/755).  Stack Exchange policy requires there to be two or more nominees, so that there is a real choice.

I realize that [several](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2848/755) people [proposed](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2849/755) that the Stack Exchange software should be changed to allow voting for "None of the above", and to allow holding an election with only one nominee.  That is not going to happen (at least not any time soon, if ever).  Such a system does not exist now.  If we want an election now, we must work within the system that exists.  Personally I do not think it would be the right use of resources to spend developer time creating that; there are many other improvements to the network that I would place as a higher priority for developers to work on.  In any case, advocacy to change the election system won't help me solve the problem we face right now.  If you want to advocate for that, you can always make your case by posting on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but right now I'm hoping we can find people who will be willing to support the site by standing for election.  For now, could I ask for your help focusing on running a successful election?

I recommend you only nominate yourself if you'd be willing to serve if you win the election.

**What do moderators do?** Moderators handle exceptional situations.  We process flags, issue suspensions, investigate vote fraud, try to facilitate discussions where needed, and step in if things get out of hand.

**How much is the time commitment?**  [Not much](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/insufficient-nominees-for-moderator-election-what-happens-next?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment6548_2847).  A few minutes a day, on average.

**Closing thoughts.**  The site is not at imminent risk of being shut down.  We do have the minimum number of mods.  But I do think we should add a fourth mod to the moderator team, to ensure the continued health of the site.  I could use the help.  Thank you for considering it!

---

**Update** (May 31): Great news -- enough people have indicated willingness to run, to enable us to hold an election.  Thank you all!  So, SE will be running an election in June.  See [Upcoming 2023 election](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2862/755) for more.

Comment: Would you share your view on competency in CS fields required, and in SE site workings (e.g. moderation & editing badges)?

Comment: @greybeard, I leave that to those who vote during the election.  I don't think it's my place to set or propose criteria.  If you're wondering about whether you'd be capable, I expect you would be capable of doing the work.

Answer (score 10):

Once again, I am happy to run. Once again, this is an election I am happy to concede if an appropriately qualified candidate steps forward and wins. This is about the community, not my fragile ego.

Answer (score 9):

I'll run! It would be a great honour!

Answer (score 8):

I can join so that Pseudonym gets elected:) If I somehow get elected, I don't mind doing the job, but please be aware that I'm more on the "aggressive" side, e.g. I have a very low tolerance for low-effort questions, so I'll probably be closing them non-stop.

Comment: Please run; I would be interested to see your election campaign.

Comment: The election nomination page is open now!  I encourage you to nominate yourself: https://cs.stackexchange.com/election.  Thank you for your service!

Comment: I'll do this during the weekends.

Answer (score 3):

I'll run for the election. I'm now pursuing a degree in computer science, and when looking for a solution in my field, I came on this  platform. And developed a liking for it. Despite not being an expert in the fields, I do my best to respond to inquiries from other CS members.

Comment: Your enthusiasm is appreciated. I am afraid you are not eligible to nominate yourself. "Any community member in good standing with more than 300 reputation (and 18 or up) may nominate themselves to be a community moderator", says [the last election page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/election/3). In fact, you are not even eligible to vote, which requires 150 reputation.

Comment: On a second thought, it is possible that you will have more than 300 reputation at the nomination phase.

Comment: The election nomination page is open now!  I encourage you to nominate yourself: https://cs.stackexchange.com/election.  Thank you for your service!

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing, it would be great honor

Comment: The election nomination page is open now!  I encourage you to nominate yourself: https://cs.stackexchange.com/election.  Thank you for your service!

Answer (score -1):

> Personally I do not think it would be the right use of resources to spend developer time creating that; there are many other improvements to the network that I would place as a higher priority for developers to work on.

Good thing those resources are spent on higher priority tasks then, like… [button styling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows)?

Comment: I'm not thrilled about that prioritization, either.  But I'm trying to find a constructive path forward that is achievable within the constraints we're under.

Comment: To be completely fair to the developers, button styling literally happens more often. The problem that CS has, which is a great problem to have, is that we're just not that competitive. Now that we have, as a community, identified an issue, we can do a work-around.

Comment: @D.W. To be clear, my answer was not disguised criticism against you: you are doing a great job for this community and I agree with your post that this is not something we could hope, at least short term. I was just expressing my surprise about some changes justified with not so convincing arguments.

Comment: @Nathaniel, all good, I didn't take it as criticism, but thanks for your comment.  I share your reaction....