# Upcoming 2023 election

Tags: discussion, election

I have an update on the election plans.  There will be an election to elect another moderator, in a few weeks: https://cs.stackexchange.com/election/4.  I thought I'd give advance notice, so those who are willing to run can prepare to nominate themselves during the week of June 13-20.  You will still need to formally nominate yourself during that time period (answers/comments here on Meta don't count).

Thank you to [everyone who has expressed willingness to run](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2855/755).  This has enabled us to ask SE to run another election.  And thanks to SE for being willing to hold this election for us!